# send get variables for pretty url

Tags: javascript, php, get, pretty-urls

I'm creating a pretty url base web and I have a problem with get variables in form.
I have a url like `localhost/events/1` (1 is a get variable $_GET['eventID']).
I want to send the eventID with a form like below

```
<select name='eventID'>
    <option value='1'>firstEvent</option>
    <option value='2'>secondEvent</option>
    <option value='3'>thirdEvent</option>
</select>
```

but when i click on submit button to send information into page and my url change to this

```
localhost/events/?eventID=1
```

but i want my url to be look like this

```
localhost/events/1
```

how could I achive to this?

Comment: Can you show us your code to send the GET request?

Comment: You should do a URL rewrite in your `.htacess` file.

Comment: @user3334871;
I just have a form to send the GET request
<form action="" method="get">
`select goes here`
<input type="submit" value="search"/>
</form>

Comment: @Rasclatt I'v already done this, I'v just have problem with my form, to send right url (pretty one) and not normal url

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean, now. I re-read your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this at the client side, you can use the javascript **onsubmit** event and redirect to the page that you want. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function yourFunction()
{
    var sel = document.getElementById('eventID');
    if (sel.selectedIndex !== -1)
    {
        window.location.href = '/events/' + sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    }

    return false;
}
</script>

<form method="get" onsubmit="return yourFunction()">
<select name="eventID" id="eventID">
    <option value="1">firstEvent</option>
    <option value="2">secondEvent</option>
    <option value="3">thirdEvent</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to W3C The question mark is part of the definition of [form submission with the GET method](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1), so you can't actually do this. but you can redirect the page with javascript.

```
 <form id="form" method="get">
 <select name='eventID'>
     <option value='1'>firstEvent</option>
     <option value='2'>secondEvent</option>
     <option value='3'>thirdEvent</option>
 </select>
 <input type="button" onclick="document.location.href= '/events/' + form.eventID.value" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all.
I want a solution without javascript or jquery
but it seems, there is no way to do this without them both.
I finally wrote some code in Jquery to solve this problem.

```
 <form id="events" method="get">
    <select name='eventID'>
     <option value='1'>firstEvent</option>
     <option value='2'>secondEvent</option>
     <option value='3'>thirdEvent</option>
    </select>
 <input type="button" onclick="document.location.href= '/events/' + form.eventID.value" value="Submit">
 </form>

$('#events').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    document.location.href= '/events/' + $(this).find('select#sportID').val();
})
```